# Google Chrome plugin/bookmarklet: "open in Firefox"?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, plugins, bookmarklet

Is there a plugin or a bookmarklet for Chrome which opens the current page in Firefox?

**Update:**

Thanks Phoshi for the suggestion. Here is my AutoHotKey script (not messing with the clipboard...):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WindowImpl_0
^+f:: ;Ctrl+Shift+F
ControlGetText, URLbartxt, Chrome_AutocompleteEditView1
RegExMatch(URLbartxt,"^((ht|f)tps?|file)://\S+$",URL)
if URL <> 
   {
   Run "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3.6 Beta\firefox.exe" %URL%
   }
return
#IfWinActive
```

But I'm still looking for a Chrome embedded solution...

Comment: From searching around the web, I don't see anything that could do that. Mirror, from Zonator.com (right on the front page, middle left), however, does open a small always-on-top window from which you can drag your URL bar contents and open it in Firefox. Drop a comment if this works and I'll put it as an answer.

Comment: Not as convenient as I would like it to be... But thanks to have looked for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
#IfWinActive [Chrome's window ID, I'll explain later]
!f:: ;Alt-F
MyClip := ClipboardAll
Send !d
Send ^c
Run P:\ath\to\firefox.exe %Clipboard%
Clipboard := MyClip
MyClip = 
return
#IfWinActive
```

That's an Autohotkey script, which would mean you had to install autohotkey, but if you don't want to do that, I can convert it into a standalone .exe.

In either case, the two things that need to be changed are the P:\ath to firefox, and Chrome's ID. I don't have chrome installed, but the Window Spy that comes with AHK can get the ID of a window, so that would do. Then, once you'd stuck this script in a text file with the extension.ahk and run it, would have Alt-F as a "firefox" key, which would quickly copy the current tab URL in GChrome, open that in FF, and return your clipboard to it's old self. AHK is very light (My 1000-liner is taking 10mb of RAM right now (To be fair, it IS running a few extra clipboards, so I don't know how much of that RAM is that), but my 15 line "Gaming Essentials" takes up something in the few kbs), so won't impact performance at all. You could also do a GChrome button, to take FF back to GChrome, but I don't know if chrome accepts the same command line arguments. If you need any help setting it up, I'm always happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have used the windows ID: ahk_class Chrome_WindowImpl_0
Not the first time that AHK help me, maybe I'm gonna learn more of this language:
Is it possible to do it without messing with the clipboard?
I think the url is directly guessable, Windows Spy:
>>>>>>>>>>>( Hidden Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Visible Text )<<<<
hxxp://superuser.com/questions/89449/google-chrome-plugin-bookmarklet-open-in-firefox
   ----   
How to assign this to a var?

Comment: (Sorry I wait a little before giving you the bounty, In case of someone came with something better...)

Comment: Hey, if you're going to put a bounty on a question, better make sure you get the best :P
I'm not too well versed in grabbing window text, but the WinGetText funtion, and string functions, could prove useful - you could also use regex to grab the first URL-formatted text. There's nothing really wrong with the clipboard approach in how it works - but it has always felt very hackish.

Comment: This didn't work for me until I put 'ClipWait' after the 'Send ^c' line. The computer was too quick for the clipboard.

Answer (score 6):

A very simple method:

In Chrome, drag the star (Address bar) to (already open) Firefox and it will open in Firefox.

It works both ways: drag the Firefox Address bar icon to Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

You can drag Chrome tabs into Firefox tab bar and it will open up in FF. Not exactly what your looking for but it might work.

Answer (score 2):

I had been using the Autohotkey solution until Chrome changed the way URLs are displayed in the latest dev version, omitting the http(s)://.

Modified code to run in the latest dev, with a new keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Menu Key to avoid conflict with some other program's global shortcut:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_0
^+AppsKey:: ;Ctrl+Shift+F
ControlGetText, URLbartxt, Chrome_AutocompleteEditView1
RegExMatch(URLbartxt,"^((ht|f)tps?|file)://\S+$",URL)
Run "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %URLbartxt%
if URL <> 
   {
   ;New Chrome versions do not display http:// in omnibar :(
   ;Run "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %URL%

   }
return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the top rated solution, I had to modify the script as shown below to work on my machine (and I prefer Win+Z key combination)

Thanks to everyone who built this solution, it works great!

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_0
#z::
ControlGetText, URLbartxt, Chrome_AutocompleteEditView1
RegExMatch(URLbartxt,"^((ht|f)tps?|file)://\S+$",URL)
if URL <> 
   {
   Run "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %URL%
   }
return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below works for me.

No need for regular expressions, changed to "Chrome_OminiboxView1", and not confirm if URLbartxt is a valid URL.

Probably this is sufficient for most people. If this code stops
working, check the adress bar with your Window Spy.

```
#z::
 IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_0
ControlGetText, URLbartxt, Chrome_OmniboxView1
   Run "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %URLbartxt%
return
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OSX, you may want to check out the latest version of [Choosy](http://www.choosyosx.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome extension for this, but it only works in OS X:

[Open with Other Apps](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omobnkkkemaadmcfiigealfphhhjeoph)

Answer (score 0):

There's also the "Mozilla Gecko Tab" extension for Chrome, it includes a context menu entry named "Open in Installed Firefox" By the way, I had to replace the class of Google Chrome into my old .ahk script with the new one (newer Chrome I think):
**Chrome_WidgetWin_0 --> Chrome_WidgetWin_1**

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
^+f:: ;Ctrl+Shift+F
ControlGetText, URLtxt, Chrome_OmniboxView1
RegExMatch(URLtxt,"^((ht|f)tps?|file)://\S+$",URL)
Run "D:\Apps\Internet\Browsers\Mozilla\Firefox\firefox.exe" %URLtxt%
return
```

The script Homepage is [here](http://npopson.com/archives/1022) (newer version of the script) thanks to Neil Popson.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of answer needs constant updates that I cannot guarantee, because a lot of apps appear and disappear, but at the present (2014) there is a Chrome Webstore app for this: [Open with external application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-external-applic/hccmhjmmfdfncbfpogafcbpaebclgjcp/related).

Both the text you get in context menu and the external program to use are editable.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: On my system (windows 7, Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m, Firefox 29.0.1) you have to use

`-new-tab [LINK_URL]`

or

`-new-window [LINK_URL]`

in the Executable parameters, otherwise only a blank firefox tab appears.