# Context menu extension in Chrome to link to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome plugin/bookmarklet: “open in Firefox”?](https://superuser.com/questions/89449/google-chrome-plugin-bookmarklet-open-in-firefox)

I was wondering if there was a way to have a right-click context menu drop down when you right-clicked on a link in Chrome and it says something to the effect of "Open link in Firefox" and it opens the link in Firefox as a result?

I'm specifically looking for Chrome -> Firefox.

Comment: An add-on to do the reverse is available - Open single/multiple firefox tabs in Chrome https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/open-in-chrome/